# Cannot log in simultaneously on different devices / browsers with the same account

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently having a login issue with CodeIgniter Web Framework.
While logged in, the user is logged in on the PC's chrome, that user cannot log in on another browser (safari, firefox ...) or other device (andoid, iphone ...)
Or, when logging in the second one, the first is automatically logged out.

Comment: you should post your code with scenario.

Comment: Can you put your code here for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't looks like it is related to CodeIgniter. It may be related to your session handling logic. Looks like condition exists for only one active session per user.